# Particular techniques for NP-complete problems

Tags: algorithms, np-complete

Is it possible to show particular classes of techniques (for instance dynamic programming) cannot produce polynomial time algorithms to any NP-complete problem?

Comment: You'd need to formalise the technique sufficiently; I don't know of formalisations of most standard techniques. In particular, Bellman's optimality criterion (the basis of DP) is informal, and several conflicting formalisations exist. If you had such a formalization, you'd then need *properties* of such a method. Something like this is not inconceivable -- we have such a theory for (canonical) greedy algorithms -- but I'm not aware of a rich body of work in this direction. (Not that I actively searched.)

Answer (score 1):

For such a broad technique as dynamic programming, the answer is almost certainly no. Suppose somebody proves that **P = NP** (and we don't know that they can't) by giving a polynomial-time algorithm for 3SAT. Surely, that algorithm could be rewritten as some kind of trivial dynamic programming, since pretty much any `for` loop can be written as dynamic programming.  For example,

```
total=0
for i=1 to n do
    total = total + data[i]
print total
```

can be rewritten as

```
total[n] = data[n]
for i=n-1 downto 1 do
    total[i] = total[i+1] + data[i]
print total[1]
```

However, one result that is in the spirit of a "yes" answer to the question is in Mihalis Yannakakis's paper "Expressing combinatorial optimization problems by Linear Programs" (*Journal of Computer and System Sciences*, 43(3):441-466, 1991; [DOI](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002200009190024Y), [free PDF](http://www.tcs.tifr.res.in/~prahladh/teaching/2011-12/comm/papers/Yannakakis1991.pdf)). This shows that any symmetric linear program for TSP must have exponential size – a linear program is symmetric if, whenever you permute the main variables, you can permute the auxiliary variables to get back the original program. Yannakakis's paper was, as I understand it, written because Ted Swart had been trying to use linear programming to solve Hamiltonian cycle in **P** and couldn't quite get the very large ($n^8$ to $n^{10}$ variables) linear programs to work.

Comment: I think you mean "memoization" where you write "dynamic programming". The vague notion of the term notwithstanding, I think some interpretation of Bellman's optimality criterion should be tied to the term. Certainly, not all problems are amenable to *this* approach of setting up a recursive algorithm, so a result of the form "no NP-complete problem fulfills [this formalisation of] Bellman's optimality criterion" is not unthinkable. Given that there *are* (super-polynomial) dynamic programming solutions to many NP-complete problems, it's inlikely though.